# Why does OSGEO/OGR add a third dimension to my 2D geometry?

Tags: python, ogr, 3d, osgeo, dimensions

When I instantiate a new `wkbPoint` geometry and give it only two coordinates, I expect it to be specifically 2D. However, a third coordinate automatically gets added as 0. See my code below:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

coords = [12, 34]

pt = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
pt.AddPoint(*coords)
print(pt.ExportToWkt())
#POINT (12 34 0)
```

Note how, at the end of the code, the `pt` variable has 3 coordinates instead of just 2. Why is this happening, and, more importantly, how can I force the creation of a 2D `Point` object?

### Note

I was able to find the answer to my own question before asking it, but I still wanted to post it here as a resource for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you're getting a 3D object is because you are using the `AddPoint` method instead of the `AddPoint_2D` method. As seen in [the `OSGEO`/`OGR`/`GDAL` documentation](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html), the `AddPoint` method expects all three coordinates as arguments: `x`, `y` and `z`. If you only pass it two arguments, it will assume `z=0`.

If, instead, you really want to work with 2D geometries, just use the `AddPoint_2D` method (and, in general, other methods that have the `_2D` suffix).

Here's an example that fixes your specific problem:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

coords = [12, 34]

pt = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
pt.AddPoint_2D(*coords)
print(pt.ExportToWkt())
#POINT (12 34)
```

Note how the geometry now only has two dimensions.